# How to mount volume for Azure single container

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service

Docker-compose yml section
volumes:
- ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/projects:/app/projects

works fine for multi-container type Azure web app. My web application works correctly and able to obtain files from "/app/projects" folder inside the container WITHOUT adding of Storage account, just clear App Service + Docker.

At the same time I can not understand where and how to provide this option to Docker container via web UI of the Azure? I need to use this option to be able to use authentication features of Azure, because for Docker-compose (multi-container) project this option is not available.

Comment: how you can acheive that ? could you please put the configuration of docker-compose and appsetting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't achieve it in the Web UI. Docker-compose YAML file is the only way to use the variable `WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME` to persist the data as known. In the Web UI, you must use the storage account to persist the data. At least currently, that's it.